# Can I clone a git repo if it already exists?

Tags: linux, git, github

I've started to use git 'properly' now so I have websites that use git repo's that I downloaded as zip files and uploaded to my server manually.

Now I know to just clone to repo using SSH and then update via SSH.

So if I have a repo on my server, is there a command I can run to apply the .git directory etc? From then on I will be able to update via SSH rather than downloading a repo manually and uploading via FTP.

Answer (score 3):

If you got a working copy with `.git` inside, all you need to do is to add a "remote link" via `git remote`:

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

Then you can send/receive commits via `git pull`/`git push`

`git clone` is basically does three things: git init, remote add and pull.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what `git clone` does. I have a local repository for a Linux distribution and I don't want to push changes to the Github repository but sometimes I end up doing commits to my local. So when a `git pull` complained that my local repository couldn't be updated, I just did a `git clone` and everything seemed fine after that. Then I thought I should find out more about what was being done and a search turned up this post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to clone a repo, make some changes, and push your changes back to the repo? That's really easy to do.

```
git clone ssh://foo
cd foo
... Make some changes
git status # See you changes
git add -u # Add all changes
git commit # Make a new commit
git push origin # Push your commit to the remote (called origin by default)
```

From this point on, you can continue to pull changes from the server with `git pull` and push your commits with `git push`.

Sounds like you're pretty new to Git. You should read [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/doc) and perhaps find a good [tutorial](http://gitimmersion.com/) to work through.